# No route to host. Github (composer) on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, github, composer-php

I'm trying to load a couple of dependencies with composer. Composer fails on a github repo. 
I also cannot browse to http://github.com and I can't reach github by ip. DNS seems fine since i can resolve github.com with nslookup.

Any suggestions?

`$ composer install
    Loading composer repositories with package information
    Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
      - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.2)
        Downloading: 100%
        Downloading: 100%
        Downloading: 100%
    Failed to download symfony/routing from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Routing/zipball/24d5f003a794894513d67c888181ba8c3b8e0693" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No route to host
    Now trying to download from source
      - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.2)
        Cloning 24d5f003a794894513d67c888181ba8c3b8e0693

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                          
  Failed to clone git@github.com:symfony/Routing.git via git, https, ssh pro  
  tocols, aborting.                                                           
  - git://github.com/symfony/Routing.git                                      
    fatal: unable to connect to github.com:                                   
    github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=No route to host                     

  - https://github.com/symfony/Routing.git                                    
    error: Failed connect to github.com:443; No route to host while accessin  
  g https://github.com/symfony/Routing.git/info/refs                          
    fatal: HTTP request failed                                                
  - git@github.com:symfony/Routing.git                                        
    ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No route to host                 
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly                                



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

`

Comment: Can you do a `git clone git@github.com:symfony/Routing.git` into a temp folder manually? Is this a local machine or a server? Can you reach `https://github.com` (i.e. not HTTP) via wget or lynx?

Comment: `$ git clone git@github.com:symfony/Routing.git
Cloning into 'Routing'...
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No route to host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
´

It's a local machine used to develop a simple proof of concept.

I cannot reach github via ssl. Not in firfox, chrome, chromium or wget. Pinging github or the ip results in 'Host unreachable'. 

I must be a faulty local setup but I have no clue where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: `traceroute 192.30.252.129` pls

Comment: `$ traceroute 192.30.252.129
traceroute to 192.30.252.129 (192.30.252.129), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.170.147.1 (192.170.147.1)  2.523 ms  2.497 ms  2.607 ms
 2  192.0.1.64 (192.0.1.64)  3001.959 ms !H  3001.954 ms !H  3001.938 ms !H`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not correlate in any form with github, composer or PHP. You got in plain English "No route to host" (github.com 192.30.252.129), i.e it's a trouble on network-layer and can't be resolved from client-side.

Test connectivity with usual `traceroute 192.30.252.129` and inform about broken path your ISP support (they escalate it higher, if needed) or corporate network administrator.

Comment: My question does relate to github since it only appears while trying to connect to github in any form. 

I did have the problem in Belgium, France, Switzerland and now in Italy (been traveling last days) so I doubt that the problem lays on the network layer.

Comment: @Bumbolt: did you get the problem in all those countries on the same machine? If so, the network layer is the problem - part of that lies within your machine. If all else fails, reinstall Ubuntu, though there's bound to be an easier fix.

Comment: Reinstalling would be a huge problem due to all the configs. I've been running this setup on the same notebook for 2y without problems.

Comment: @Bumbolt - why you use these IPs - `192.170.147.1` + `192.170.147.1` (from 192.0.0.0/8 net) **in Europe**? It's ARIN (North America) [space](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-192-0-0-0-0/pft) (except private 192.168.0.0/16)

Comment: I don't mean to use them. I didn't add any exceptions for github.